# Problem with IPv6 & ACPI on Asus

Tags: kernel, acpi, ipv6, dmesg

My Ubuntu lags after the login window. I checked and the reason is IPv6 and ACPI! What's wrong with my system?

[the dmesg pasted here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23094084/)

Comment: Do you have an ipv6 compatible router? Have you tried setting your ethernet network setting for ipv6 **ignore**? What kind of ethernet card/driver are you running? Cheers, Al

Comment: I don't use my laptop for internet much. I disabled ipv6 from etc/sysctl.conf and my DE crashed! also my ethernet is JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

Comment: What command did you use in sysctl.conf? The easy way to do it is **Edit Connections** from the network icon in the top panel. Open the **Wired Connection** script, go to the ipv6 tab, and use the pop-up selection. Cheers, Al

Comment: This has nothing to do with IPv6.

Comment: then what's the problem please